# How to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 DDE to 20.04 DDE

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, deepin-desktop-environment

Willing to upgrade my Deepin Desktop Environment (DDE) based on Ubuntu 18.04 I was confronted with the lack of explanation on how to do so reliably to 20.04 DDE.

Any enlightened, safe method on how to do so?

Note: As DDE is considered a re-spin on Ubuntu I was informed to post the question here instead of AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First, start doing the upgrade (it's ok to do it from DDE terminal) from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa):

First, make sure that your system is already up-to-date. Run a full Ubuntu update and upgrade with Apt.

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then, before you begin to upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa you may also want to remove all no longer required packages using:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

If you know what you're doing (if not, refer to the linked post), issue the following to start the update process from 18.04 to 20.04:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Ubuntu will ask you a couple of questions about how you want to handle the upgrade, and it'll start off upgrading your system.

You may be asked a few questions during the update process, review them carefully. In my case I only had to answer (Y) each time.

At the end of the upgrade process, tyou will receive a prompt to restart the system. Answer No or (N).

Secondly, follow the install procedure to install DDE on 20.04 as issued [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu/):

Step 1: Add UbuntuDDE Stable PPA repository

If you had tried other PPA repositories such as leaeasy without any success I recommend you clean them out.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:leaeasy/dde
```

Add Stable PPA repository for DDE:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
```

Hit the Enter key in your keyboard to add the repository.

Step 2: Install Deepin Desktop Environment (DDE) on Ubuntu 20.04

After adding the repository successfully the next step will be to install Deepin Desktop Environment (DDE) on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntudde-dde
```

Step 3: Using Deepin Desktop Environment (DDE) on Ubuntu 20.04

Be careful: don't restart your machine yet. Instead, issue the following

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

In order to be sure all the components of DDE are updated successfully.

Reboot and repeat that last step, by any chance.

This is done because there are relatively few articles on how to debug DDE on Ubuntu so better proceed carefully to avoid them. This walkthrough should avoid most of the caveats you could meet in the process.

Enjoy!